# Prisma - Update one resource under more condition

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I would like to know if it is possible to update a resource under multiple condition.
For example, consider the following two table:

```
+----------+----------+
|  Table1  |  Table2  |
+----------+----------+
| id       | id       |
| param1T1 | param1T2 |
| param2T1 | param2T2 |
| idTable2 |          |
+----------+----------+
```

I would like to update a record into table `Table1` where I know the filed `id` that is the `primary key` AND where `idTable2` have a specific value.

Using the `.update()` method I have an error during compile time but I don't understand why I can't update a single identity using more condition.
This is my update:

```
table1.update({
  where: {
    AND: [
      { id: 1 },
      { Table2: { id: 1 } }
    ]
  },
  data: toUpdate
 });
```

Now, I resolve the problem using `.updateMany()` instead the `.update()`. There is a solution or is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but I bumped into the same question in 2023, so I'll leave a solution I found for whoever googled here.

#### Short Answer

Using `AND` needs to be enabled like this:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["extendedWhereUnique"]
}
```

#### More Info

You can find discussion about this feature on Prisma's GitHub in [this post](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/4185).

Originally answered at [this comment](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/4185#discussioncomment-6191666).